# C# Icons do not fit in picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, picturebox

First of all I have two computers. One of them is notebook.Other one is desktop PC.

In Desktop, if I want to add 16x16 icon, I add 16x16 picturebox and select 16x16 icon. It is enough for this process.

In Notebook, I already do same things but icon does not fit to picturebox (also shown with attachment).

At the same time if I moved some projects from my desktop pc, 32x32 pictureboxes changed to 43x39. What is my problem? Can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: By the way , I discovered something. I set to picturebox size 16x16 and check size of picBox , it shows 12x13

Answer (score 2):

There are five different `PictureBoxSizeMode` is available to `PictureBox` control.

```
 AutoSize       - Sizes the picture box to the image.
 CenterImage    - Centers the image in the picture box.
 Normal         - Places the upper-left corner of the image at upper
                  left in the picture box
 StretchImage   - Allows you to stretch the image in code
```

The `PictureBox` is not a selectable control, which means that it cannot receive input focus.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, I already know sizemodes for picturebox. My problem is in Desktop --> size mode = normal ---> Fits good. Notebook---> size mode= Normal --> fits like attachment

Comment: Welcome Uygar if your problem is solved please accept the answer.

Comment: Nope , its not solution for me. Because both computer size mode is Normal. Desktop fits greater but notebook its not.

Comment: What do you mean? You need to stretch the picture,  that fixed your problem.

Comment: In designer i set size to 16x16 , i also add console.writeline(pbox.size) to load event and pbox shows 12x13 btw i dont want to use autosize for some situations

Answer (score 0):

Try Setting **Anchor** property of the **PictureBox**.
Anchor it depending to your needs and it should resize the Picturebox as and when the size of Main Window changes.

Also, make sure the PictureBoxSizeMode property is set to **AutoSize** so that the picture adjusts too with the PictureBox.

Answer (score 0):

Some Bugs on VS 2015 Community 2015 Update 3 ,

While program compiling , vs does not set pictureBox sizes truely. Update 1 works fine.